# ign gazebo collada meshes issue

Tags: collada, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to spawn a model with dae texture files and they don't load correctly in the GzScene3D.
If you look the camera plugin, the texture was loaded well, but in the scene it is a mess.
I tried to use models from fuel, but all that have dae texture cause the same problem.

I'm using Ignition Citadel.

[image: image description]

Any pointers where to find a solution are highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26697/ign-gazebo-collada-meshes-issue/) by [Filipe Almeida](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44819/filipe-almeida/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on 2021-04-01**:
tweaking some parameters in the Colladaloader file may help, not sure though.

**Comment by [Filipe Almeida](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44819/filipe-almeida/) on 2021-04-05**:
I don't know how I can change that parameters. I tried different versions and different computers and got the same issue.

**Comment by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on 2021-04-05**:
Trying on different machines won't necessarily solve the issue when there's a problem with the .dae file. What I am trying to say is that try scaling your file in the blender or any other app.

**Comment by [Filipe Almeida](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44819/filipe-almeida/) on 2021-04-06**:
Right, but I did not use the same mesh in the tests. I tried different models from fuel (models that was demonstrated in the tutorials). I tested with many models from fuel and all that use collada meshes have the same issue. This is not related with my collada mesh.

**Comment by [olmer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/222/olmer/) on 2021-05-17**:
Did you solve the problem? I think that I have the same problem, if I see in ogre2.og say and error about textures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I solve the problem, I added `export LC_NUMERIC="C"` before to run ign gazebo.

The problem is [described here](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/issues/353#issuecomment-694402814)

---

Originally posted by [olmer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/222/olmer/) with karma: 36 on 2021-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on 2021-05-21**:
I was facing the same issue with some models like [this](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/issues/679). I tried exporting this and it worked for me. Thanks.

**Comment by [Filipe Almeida](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44819/filipe-almeida/) on 2021-05-25**:
Thank you!!!! It solve that problem!!! Now is loading collada meshes without that issue!